# AngularFire hasCustomClaim and customClaims not working

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I have been trying to use Firebase custom claims and successfully able to create user-based roles like, `manager, editor, admin`. This is how my custom claim is saved in my Firebase Emulator Suite.

For user custom clams are set like this `{"role": "manager"}`, but whenever I tried to login and get the custom claim of the user it doesn't work.

Just an FYI I tried to set custom claims like this too `{"manager": true}` but `hasCustomClaim("manager")` always works if I use this in `if and else` condition even if I set `{"manager": false}` also if i try to login using admin privileges but still manager level works properly

```
const adminOnly = () => hasCustomClaim("admin");
const editorOnly = () => hasCustomClaim("editor");
const managerOnly = () => hasCustomClaim("manager" ); 

const editorOnly2d = pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.role == "editor"));
const mngOnly2 = pipe(customClaims, map(claims => claims.role == "manager"));
```

How shall I get current logged in user custom claims so that I can set routes based on user role?

This is what I get after login `authUser.getIdTokenResult(true)`

```
aud: "testing" 
auth_time: 1629796111 
email: "test12@gmail.com" 
email_verified:false 
exp: 1629799711 
firebase: {identities: {…}, sign_in_provider: "password"} 
iat: 1629796111 
iss: "https://securetoken.google.com/testing" 
role: "manager" 
name: "Testing" 
sub: "ZUlXd59HMhFI5gyozxW1xw0IXtPi" 
user_id: "ZUlXd59HMhFI5gyozxW1xw0IXtPi"
```

I tried to search the issue, but all of them suggest the same thing that I used above.

Comment: Custom claims are a feature of Firebase Authentication, and not of Firestore. I fixed that for you, but it's something to keep in mind for future questions. By labeling and tagging your question correctly, the people with the right knowledge to help are more likely to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The `{"role": "manager"}` will not work, because `hasCustomClaim("admin")` (as far as I can see) only checks for the existence of a claim *named* `admin`.

That also explains why it works when you use `"manager": false`, `hasCustomClaim` merely checks for the presence of the claim regardless of its value. Non-admins should not have an `admin` claim.

So if you want to use the existing AngularFire pipes, you'll need claims that identify whether the user is an `admin`, `editor`, and/or `manager`.

If you want to use your own role-based access control, that is possible too, but you'll have to implement your own auth pipe filters. For those, you'll want to start by logging the `claims`, so you can see what you're `map` call is working against.

Comment: Hi frank thanks for your response, this is what I thought too but while debugging I thought maybe it checks for existence so I  tried this
        `if(adminOnly){ console.log('You are admin') }else{
             console.log('not admin')}
          if(managerOnly){  console.log('you are a manager')  }else{  console.log('not a manager')}` 
 but in both case I got `'You are admin'` and `'You are a manager'` at same time.so I think while login i need to use `authUser.getIdTokenResult(true)` and get custom claims

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean there. Can you show the `console.log()` of the user's existing ID token (so without forcing a refresh) in your question? If the `role` claim is not in there yet, it makes sense that the code doesn't work. Note that it takes up to an hours for claims to propagate from the server to the client, as the client only refreshes the ID token once per hour (unless you force a refresh in your code).

Comment: Hi frank, User roles are already there,  please check `aud: "testing"
auth_time: 1629796111
email: "test12@gmail.com"
email_verified: false
exp: 1629799711
firebase: {identities: {…}, sign_in_provider: "password"}
iat: 1629796111
iss: "https://securetoken.google.com/testing"
manager: true
name: "Testing"
sub: "ZUlXd59HMhFI5gyozxW1xw0IXtPi"
user_id: "ZUlXd59HMhFI5gyozxW1xw0IXtPi"`

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, as it becomes quite hard to quickly scan in a comment like this. But: I don't see a `role` claim in there, which would explain why your custom filters don't work as they check for `claims.role == "editor"`.